# turn $D=\{(x,y) | x \leq y \leq 2x, a\sqrt{x} \leq y \leq b \sqrt{x}, x\geq 0, 0 <a<b\}$ into a rectangle

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

Im trying to transform the region $D=\{(x,y) | x \leq y \leq 2x, a\sqrt{x} \leq y \leq b \sqrt{x}, x\geq 0, 0 <a<b\}$ to a rectangle by using a variable change.

I'm doing this in order to calculate $\int_{D}x^{-\frac{3}{2}}dxdy$

since this region $D$ is not so simple, I drew it on a piece of paper 
[image: Graph of region D is highlighted]

I apologize for the photo being inverted. I don't know how to fix it.

I would like someone to assist me think of a diffeomorphism that would transform this region into a simple rectangle.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: you could try to parametrize your region by a family of curves $y=u\sqrt{x}$ and a family of lines $y=vx$. More explicitly,
$$
x=\frac{u^2}{v^2}, \quad y = \frac{u^2}{v}.
$$
I think that $a \leq u \leq b$ and $1\leq v \leq 2$.

Comment: Very creative. Well done sir.

Comment: Is the final answer (for the integral) $2(b-a) \log 2$?

Comment: I didn't compute the integral, sorry.